# Get correct text height for iOS 7 in iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6, uilabel

I need to get text height and grow cell's height depending upon text height which increase or decrease dynamically. I now successfully getting correct height of text for iOS 6 and prior but I am not able to get correct height iOS 7 and later. I googled and found many solution but this doesn't worked. You can see attached Image of same cell and see difference in iOS 7 text is truncating and in iOS 6 its showing correct size. I used `UILabel`. Follow my code of what exactly I am doing. Kindly look into it and guide me better solution if any one experienced this sort of thing earlier.

```
- (CGSize)getSizeOfText:(NSString *)text withFont:(UIFont *)font widthOftext:(int )txtWidth
{
CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(txtWidth, 9999);
CGSize size;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{
    CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                         context:nil];
    size=textRect.size;
}
else
{
    CGSize requiredSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:boundingSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    size=requiredSize;
}

return size;
}
```

**On iOS 6 device.**
[image: iOS 6]

**On iOS 7 device.**
[image: iOS 7]

Comment: FYI - do not check the `systemVersion`. Check for the existence of the `boundingRectWithSize` method instead.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for reply but FYI, sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: deprecated in iOS 7 you can see at here "https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html"

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

Declare #define kMaxHeight 1000.0f in header.

```
        CGSize sizeNew = [YourText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:Fontname size:intFontSize]
                 constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, kMaxHeight)
                     lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
         txtText.numberOfLines = 0;
```

If you have any question let m e know.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still same text is truncating:(.

Comment: I tried to give minimum width of instead of actual width of uilabel but I couldn't get exact width where it show me right text which is fitted as like iOS 6.

Comment: any other approach which I should follow?

Comment: @josh every time you get same result in sizeNew?

Comment: :NO, As you can see first four cell's text titles return height values are {39.101562,39.101562,19.550781,58.652344}.

Comment: Here is return height of first 4 cells for iOS6 version is {42.000000,42.000000,21.000000,42.000000}

Comment: I am bit confuse on 4th cell's text height which is quite major difference.

Comment: Have you implemented this function already in your code? and also did you get some info from above height values is that how we will make this right.?

Comment: I think, iOS 6's code gives us info text's line by line unlike iOS 7 code which is giving us info just text by text. So thats why iOS6 code working perfectly fine.