# UILabel can't get multiples lines on increasing dynamic height of text in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilabel

I am developing an app, in which I am getting dynamic text and I have to increase height of label dynamically depending upon text and also increase and decrease height of table cell on basis on label height. So I wrote code both for iOS 6 and iOS7 and it works fine in iOS 6 but in iOS7 it not working fine. Below is code. Function that return height of text.

```
- (CGSize)getSizeOfText:(NSString *)text withFont:(UIFont *)font widthOftext:(int )txtWidth
{



  CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(txtWidth, 1000);
CGSize size;
if (MyDelegate.isIos7)
{

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize
                                      options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                   attributes:attributesDictionary
                                      context:nil];

    return frame.size;
}
else
{
    CGSize requiredSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:boundingSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    size=requiredSize;
}

return size;
}
```

There is bit change on return of height for iOS 6 and iOS 7.
Below First four label's text height difference for both them.

**iOS6**

1. 42.000000
2. 42.000000
3. 21.000000
4. 42.000000

**iOS7**

1. 39.674072
2. 39.674072
3. 20.123291
4. 39.674072

You can see bit difference of first four texts. But One major problem more in iOS is that It always show me text in just one line and truncate text even text height goes to 39 which may come in 2 lines, I also set number of lines to 20 and also tried to set number line to just 0 but didn't work.

Kindly guide me on this if anyone already this sort of problem. Thanks

**Edited**
I already posted this question earlier if anyone want to see screen shots of both iOS results so check there also.
[Same Thread with Screen Shots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652743/get-correct-text-height-for-ios-7-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Check my Answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652743/get-correct-text-height-for-ios-7-in-iphone-sdk/22653021#22653021

Comment: Sorry Didn't worked :(

Comment: Also what you suggest is deprecated in iOS 7.

Comment: use the `sizeThatFits:` method instead. That will work. Also, the documentation for `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` states that `This method returns fractional sizes (in the size component of the returned CGRect); to use a returned size to size views, you must use raise its value to the nearest higher integer using the ceil function.`, which you're not doing.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: @Matthias Bauch, sorry I know but I was stuck from yesterday and no body gave me answer. On Today I first edit this question to come into edited column but still no body gave me answer, so because of not getting answer and stuck on same issue. I will have to create new question with added some more info, and finally I got answer, so whats big deal. Kindly make also solution for old questions to get updates.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set this property to your label

> label.numberOfLines = 3;

it should solve the problem and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the label to `frame.size.height+1` or round it up.
and of course make sure the numberOfLines of your label is 3 (or 0 if you think it is possible to show more than 3).

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way for dynamic change of height for cell using UITableView. This works for me for IOS7 and IOS6 also

```
At   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSString *cellText=yourtextstring;
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Bold" size:13.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(300.0f, MAXFLOAT);//225
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
                    //NSLog(@"*** labelSize.height *** %f",labelSize.height);
        return labelSize.height+250; //change this as per your need
    }

  At   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *cellText=yourtextstring;
        UIFont *cellFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Regular" size:13.0];
        CGSize constraintSize=CGSizeMake(300,MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize txtViewSize=[cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        CGRect frame=cell.yourlabel.frame;

     //   frame.size.width=300;
        frame.size.height=txtViewSize.height+150;
        cell.yourlabel.frame=frame;

        cell.yourlabe.text=cellText;
        return cell;
    }
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

NO need to compare for iOS 6 and iOS 7 
use like below

```
  CGFloat txtWidth = 250.0f;
  NSString *font = @"Noteworthy-Bold"; //say u hav font
  NSString *text = @"Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text"; //say u hav some text
 UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:font size:15];
 NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:labelFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributesDictionary];
 CGRect frame = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){txtWidth, MAXFLOAT}
                                           options: (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                           context:nil];//you need to specify the some width, height will be calculated
 CGSize requiredSize = frame.size;
 NSLog(@"wdth->%f height->%f",requiredSize.width,requiredSize.width);
 //248.962509 height->248.962509 //iOS 7
 //248.962494 height->248.962494 //iOS 6
 //almost same 
 //also set 'numberOfLines` property of label
```